# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'InvestmentId') on WebSocket with Cypress

Tags: javascript, websocket, cypress

I'm trying to get messages from a WebSocket to make assertions using Cypress. I used the example from the website [link] (https://github.com/lensesio/cypress-websocket-testing/blob/master/README.md) to do the automation.

Basically, I made a post to a Rest service and then I listen to WebSocket to see if any new messages are displayed.

The first statement passes, but the second does not. Cypress displays a message saying: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'InvestmentId')".

The cy.log command does not print anything to the console. I think the return message from the WebSocket is not being stored in the result variable.

It looks like cypress is not reading all messages sent by WebSocket. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```js
expect(result.body.payload).to.have.property('InvestmentId')
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try now. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.to.not.be.undefined` on the property

```js
expect(result.payload.InvestmentId).to.not.be.undefined
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: From the passing log, `result` is an array - can you please console.log() result otherwise, trying to guess the correct structure. With an array maybe it's `expect(result[0].payload.InvestmentId).to.eq('906')`.

Comment: The cy.log() command didn't show anything. I think the WebSocket response is not coming from the variable result.

Comment: I tried to make the assertion with expect(result[0].payload.InvestmentId).to.eq('906') and it didn't work either.

Comment: `cy.log()` is bad for debugging, use `console.log()` as I suggested. In any case, it looks like the ws response does not have what you are expecting - congratulation, you found a bug!

Comment: console.log didn't work either.

Comment: Not really the point - your streamRequest is faulty.